# Height of cabinet for induction cooktop

Tags: kitchens, stove

I just bought a new apartment, and purchased a new Bosch induction cooktop for the kitchen.
The cut in the counter top stone is the right size, but when I placed it inside I see that the bottom of the cooktop is very close to the drawer beneath it.
This doesn't cause a problem to open or close the drawer, but i was wondering if the bottom of the cooktop heats up, or can be bad/dangerous in any way because of being too close to the drawer.

Comment: Have you considered [calling Bosch](http://www.bosch-home.com/us/support/contact-us.html) about it? There's no better source for safety information than the company that makes the device you're using. Additionally, their website has all of the installation info PDFs... you don't say which cooktop you have, specifically, so it's impossible for us to tell you if there's a minimum space underneath required.

Comment: This should really be on the Home Improvement stackexchange, since it has to do with appliance installation. But really, just go to Bosch's website and download the installation instructions PDF if your cooktop didn't come with it.

Answer (score -2):

Try it & see if you don't like it. ALL cooktops are zero clearance to counters & drawers, gas or electric...always have been. Bosch is no different whether it's induction or not. They just want you about 2" from the countertop front & back for pot & pan clearances.

Other than that, if you don't need the drawer for it's current use. You can turn it into a plate warmer by lining it with tin foil. This will put any fire worries to rest & you'll even be able to keep food warm, not hot, just warm.

Comment: Induction cooktops will, well, cook if not provided with adequate ventilation. The electronics overheat and you get all sorts of fun bugs. Manufacturer's mandatory clearances are mandatory for a reason.